# Displaying folders only containing files with certain file type

Tags: android

I have set up code to display all folders that are on the SD card but now I am trying to figure out how to only display folders which contain MP3 files.

How can I filter out the folders that don't contain .MP3 files? thanks.

class:

```
public class FragmentFolders extends ListFragment {
private File file;
private List<String> myList;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    file = new File(root_sd);

    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));

}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    File temp_file = new File(file, myList.get(position));

    if (!temp_file.isFile()) {
        file = new File(file, myList.get(position));
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        myList.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            myList.add(list[i].getName());
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));

    }

    return;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the files within a directory are mp3 files before adding to your list view's dataset

Modify your code as follows:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        file = new File(root_sd);

        //list content of root sd

        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

                //check the contents of each folder before adding to list

                File  mFile = new File(file, list[i].getName());
                File dirList[] = mFile.listFiles();
                   if(dirList == null) continue;
                  for (int j = 0; j < dirList.length; j++) {
                    if(dirList[j].getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).endsWith(".mp3")){
                    myList.add(list[i].getName());
                    break;
                    }
              }

        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));
}
```

I tested this and it works. Only caveat is, it doesn't check for sub-directories.

So in:

```
sdcard/Music/mistletoe.mp3
sdcard/Media/Tracks/mistletoe.mp3
```

only the Music folder will be listed.

Also, you may want to use an asyncTask to eschew hogging the UI thread

Comment: what to do for sub-directories?

Answer (score 1):

You can user a fileNameFilter and filter out the folders/files you don't want.

```
File baseDirectory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/"); //Your base dir here
File[] files = baseDirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String fileName) {
    File possibleMp3Folder = new File(dir, fileName);
    if (possibleMp3Folder.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files1 = possibleMp3Folder.listFiles();
        for (File file : files1) {
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
   }

   return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all *folders contains **mp3*** files (both on Internal storage and SD Card) and available *storages contains **media***:

1. Initialize two Sets for *media storage paths* and *mp3 folders paths*:

   ```
   private HashSet<String> storageSet = new HashSet<>();
   private HashSet<String> folderSet = new HashSet<>();
   ```
2. Get both in one method (you can return value if you need only one):

   ```
   private void getMediaFolders() {
       ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

       Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
       String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
       String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };

       Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, projection, selection, null, null);

       if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
           int dataIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

           while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
               String data = cursor.getString(dataIndex);

               int i = 0;
               for (int slashCount = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                   if (data.charAt(i) == '/' && ++slashCount == 3) {
                       storageSet.add(data.substring(0, i));
                       break;
                   }
               }

               if (data.toLowerCase().endsWith("mp3")) {
                   int lastSlashIndex = data.lastIndexOf('/');
                   while (i < lastSlashIndex) {
                       data = data.substring(0, lastSlashIndex);
                       folderSet.add(data);
                       lastSlashIndex = data.lastIndexOf('/');
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       if (cursor != null) { cursor.close(); }
   }
   ```
3. Filter folders (with Annimonstream):

   ```
   private ArrayList<File> getFilteredFolders(@NonNull String path, HashSet<String> folderSet) {
       File[] filesList = new File(path).listFiles();

       if (filesList == null) { return new ArrayList<>(); } // Or handle error as you wish

       return Stream.of(filesList)
           .filter(File::isDirectory)
           .filter(f -> folderSet.contains(f.getAbsolutePath()))
           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
   }
   ```
4. Show storages (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

```
               Uri,Projection,
                            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA
                            + " like " + "'%.mp4%'"
                            + " AND "
                            + MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA
                            + " like " + "'%" + getResources().
                            getString(R.string.string_store_video_folder) 
                            +"%'", null,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED
```

this will give mp4 files in a specific folder