# how to get folders only containing audio file (.mp3) in android

Tags: android, directory, subdirectory, audio-player, android-music-player

I am making music player with folder functionality and i want to show only folder which is containing music or audio files like .mp3, just like MX Player(show only folders which have video files). I have try code for this but its give all directories. Here is my code

```
public static List<File> getListFiles(@NonNull File directory, @Nullable FileFilter fileFilter) {
    List<File> fileList = new LinkedList<>();
    File[] found = directory.listFiles(fileFilter);

    if (found != null) {
        Collections.addAll(fileList, found);
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

I have also try answer of [Displaying folders only containing files with certain file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881434/displaying-folders-only-containing-files-with-certain-file-type) this question, but its check for directory, it doesn't check for sub-directories. Help me if possible. Thanks in Advance.